# How to use Jenkins secret file credentials as input to my Jenkins Plugin?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, credentials

As a newbie in Jenkins Plugin Development, I have difficulties in finding useful learning resources. In this specific case, I want to use Jenkins secret file credentials as input parameter to my plugin, so I can secure the secret keys. But I don't know where to start.

Comment: The credentials plugin's [consumer guide](https://github.com/jenkinsci/credentials-plugin/blob/master/docs/consumer.adoc) solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [credentials plugin wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin) then there is a list of the plugins (probably not exhaustive) which consume credentials.

I would suggest that you look through some of these plugins to see how they work.

Parameters are a separate thing which relates to a run of a job, rather than the definition of the job. I would start by adding a default credential choice into the global config of you plugin and then investigate how you can override that using a parameter.

Historically, the hello-world plugin had a global config, this now seems to be covered by the [archetypes tooling](https://github.com/jenkinsci/archetypes/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1.- Define a credential of type Secret file.

2.- On your plugin configuration, add a text box to allow the user to enter the id of the credential.

3.- Retrieve the credential by its id:

```
        FileCredentials fileCredentials = CredentialsProvider.findCredentialById(credentialsId, FileCredentials.class,run,
                new DomainRequirement());

        String apiKeyFromCredentials = IOUtils.toString(fileCredentials.getContent());
```